# Customer service roles

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, user-roles

I am very new to magento. I am thinking of using magento as ecommerce platform for our company.

I'll have an offshore team who will provide customer service and also take phone orders. I am thinking of giving each customer service rep a role in magento admin so that they can view customer orders, take phone orders, do cancellations and refunds etc.

Is magento admin designed to be used by customer service reps, say around 200 of them? 
or there is a better way?

Orders will go to a crm system from magento and customer service reps will also have access to it to log conversation details.

Answer (score 2):

Magento is setup to allow for CSR's using the backend and the build in ACL will allow you to restrict access to areas where you want you CSR's to navigate to.

200 people in Admin is a lot and you will want to work with a Hosting or Solution partner that can build out the right environment for you. The admin section will not cache the same as your frontend so you will want to take that into account with designing your environment.

There is a notes section in Admin to add details to an order and there are a number of extensions that you can add to enhance this.

Comment: We don't have 200 CSR right now but I just want to know that by allowing CSR to access admin using right ACL, are we on right path?

We can obviously add caching and improve admin performance if needed but re-training CSR to totally new system later on will be a problem. I guess all performance related changes will be transparent to CSR. correct?

Comment: Since I don't know you requirements on what areas you want CSR's access to it is impossible to say Yes or No to you question. Why don't you simply get a install and test?

Comment: As I said earlier, I want them to be able to view orders, take phone orders, cancel and do refunds. I already have magento demo installed and I can do all these functions myself. What I am interested to know is whether large magento based ecommerce stores give csr access access to these functions in magento or they make them do it via some other system? and if so, why? Isn't magento backend designed to be used by csr?

Copying orders and it's changes back and forth between two systems is a big job. and that will be true for products too.

Comment: What you can do with your one demo store you can do in scale. All you need is more server resources. Once you add in your CRM and ERP there are infinite possibilities that could not possibly answered here.

Comment: Thanks for input. I am still trying to find some good crm and erp extensions for magento. If you know good ones, please update me.

Comment: With 200 CSR's you will want to go with a stand alone system. With 200 employees you may want to consider using something like SAP or Netsuite for your ERP.